# PHP Doctrine Load 3 entities by one SQL query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I would like ask you if possible create in native doctrine method preload subproperty. Not by lazy loading.

For example:
I have 3 entities. (Product, Item, Colour).

Product has ManyToMany relation on Item and item has ManyToMany relation on Colour.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Item", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="product_item",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
     * )
     */
private $items;
```

-

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="item")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ItemRepository")
     */
    class Item
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="items")
     */
     private $products;

   /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Colour", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *     name="item_colour",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="colour_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
     * )
     */
     private $colours;
```

-

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="colour")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ColourRepository")
     */
    class Colour
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Item", mappedBy="colours")
     */
     private $items;
```

And i have this code:

```
$products = $productRepository->findAll();

foreach ($products as $product){
   $items = $product->getItems();

   foreach ($items as $item){
      // Do some
   }
}
```

Can i use something for only one SQL to DB?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
$query = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('p')
            ->from(Product::class, 'p')
            ->leftJoin('p.discount', 'discount')
            ->leftJoin('p.productLanguages', 'productLanguages')
            ->leftJoin('p.combinationsInfo', 'combinationsInfo')
            ->leftJoin('p.tableSize', 'tableSize')
            ->leftJoin('p.state', 'state')
            ->leftJoin('p.tags', 'tags')
            ->leftJoin('p.categories', 'categories')
            ->leftJoin('p.images', 'images')
            ->leftJoin('p.similarProducts', 'similarProducts')
            ->leftJoin('p.similarProductsReverse', 'similarProductsReverse')
            ->leftJoin('p.partnerProducts', 'partnerProducts')
            ->leftJoin('p.partnerProductsReverse', 'partnerProductsReverse')
            ->leftJoin('p.mainCategory', 'mainCategory')
            ->leftJoin('p.variants', 'variants')
            ->leftJoin('p.type', 'type')
            ->leftJoin('p.sex', 'sex')

            ->leftJoin('discount.discountLanguages', 'discountDiscountLanguages')

            ->leftJoin('productLanguages.tax', 'productLanguagesTax')
            ->leftJoin('productLanguages.currency', 'productLanguagesCurrency')
            ->leftJoin('productLanguages.language', 'productLanguagesLanguage')

            ->leftJoin('images.categories', 'imagesCategories')
            ->leftJoin('images.widgets', 'imagesWidgets')
            ->leftJoin('images.reporters', 'imagesReporters')

            ->leftJoin('categories.categoryLanguages', 'categoriesCategoryLanguages')
            ->leftJoin('categories.type', 'categoriesType')
            ->leftJoin('categories.images', 'categoriesImages')
            ->leftJoin('categories.reporters', 'categoriesReporters')
            ->leftJoin('categories.parent', 'categoriesParent')
            ->leftJoin('categories.descendants', 'categoriesDescendants')

            ->leftJoin('categoriesDescendants.categoryLanguages', 'categoriesDescendantsCategoryLanguages')
            ->leftJoin('categoriesDescendants.type', 'categoriesDescendantsType')
            ->leftJoin('categoriesDescendants.images', 'categoriesDescendantsImages')
            ->leftJoin('categoriesDescendants.reporters', 'categoriesDescendantsReporters')
            ->leftJoin('categoriesDescendants.parent', 'categoriesDescendantsParent')
            ->leftJoin('categoriesDescendants.descendants', 'categoriesDescendantsDescendants')

            ->leftJoin('mainCategory.categoryLanguages', 'mainCategoryCategoryLanguages')
            ->leftJoin('mainCategory.type', 'mainCategoryType')
            ->leftJoin('mainCategory.images', 'mainCategoryImages')
            ->leftJoin('mainCategory.reporters', 'mainCategoryReporters')
            ->leftJoin('mainCategory.parent', 'mainCategoryParent')
            ->leftJoin('mainCategory.descendants', 'mainCategoryDescendants');
```

Comment: which version on Doctrine do you use ?

Comment: I use symfony 3, so doctrine 2 (i think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example joins in the Doctrine documentation.
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.address a WHERE a.city = 'Berlin'");
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use following DQL to get the results

```
SELECT p,i
FROM Product p
JOIN p.items i /* or LEFT JOIN to get all products */
```

Comment: ok, if i have huge entity and i want load 3 layers to deep, so i have to use this? viz edit question.

Comment: Yes i see your updated post. you query builder will also generate single sql and DQL which you can print by doing `$query->getSQL()` or  `$query->getDQL()`